# How to make a WPF TextBox pass-through ApplicationCommands?

Tags: wpf

The WPF TextBox captures Ctrl-Z and Ctrl-Y for its own undo/redo. Normally great, but in our app we have some text boxes that I don't want to have this behavior, but to instead pass through to the overall app to handle as global undo.

I figured out I can override the text boxes' handling of these by adding CommandBindings for ApplicationCommands.Undo/Redo.

My question: how can I 'forward' those bindings to the parent framework element so that it eventually routes to the app's handler I installed on the main window?

**Update:** Thanks to AndrewS it turns out all I needed was to set IsUndoEnabled to false. Then the app commands get ignored and the top level window can handle them. Yay!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to register a KeyBinding for the shortcut and associated it with the ApplicationCommands.NotACommand. e.g.

```
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Y" Modifiers="Control" Command="NotACommand" />
            <KeyBinding Key="Z" Modifiers="Control" Command="NotACommand" />
        </TextBox.InputBindings>
    </TextBox>
```

Comment: BTW you may also want to set the IsUndoEnabled to false so it doesn't waste memory managing its undo history.

Comment: Hey that's interesting. Didn't even know NotACommand existed.. Out of curiosity how would this be made localizable? (I assume Chinese keyboards don't use Ctrl+Z for Undo.)

Comment: I don't know of any good way to get that. If you look at the System.Windows.Input.ApplicationCommands.LoadDefaultGestureFromResource method (e.g. in reflector/uispy) they are getting the key from their own resources but I don't know that they surface it. You would probably need to get the InputGestures of ApplicationCommand.(Undo|Redo) and then dynamically add the InputBindings. You might be able to do that in your own attached behavior.

Comment: One other option might be to add a handler (using AddHandler and passing true to be called for handled events) on the TextBox for the CommandManager.CanExecute event. When the e.Command is Undo|Redo you could set the ContinueRouting on the CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs to true.

Comment: Well how about that. Turns out all I needed to do was set IsUndoEnabled to false and the commands are passed right on through.

Comment: Setting IsUndoEnabled to false doese not help, at least not in my case. I'm using RichTextBox (although neither TextBox did pass through ApplicationCommands) encapsulated in UserControl, which I used in one of my views (MVVM, Caliburn.Micro as supporting MVVM framework). For localization purposes, it might be suitable to use an attached property with a list of disabled application commands.